# JWT-Node authentication - req.headers[''authorization"] is Undefined

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I try to set Token then get token from header but it always shows "undefined" when i console.log(req.headers['authorization'])

Here is some code

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const accessTokenSecret = 'youraccesstokensecret';
app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log('Authentication service started on port 8080');
});
```

I set token

```
app.get("/createJWT",function(req,res){
    const accessToken = jwt.sign({ username: "myName"}, accessTokenSecret);

    res.json({
        accessToken
    });
})
```

the middleware (I show req.headers['authorization'] is undefined)

```
const authenticateJWT = (req, res, next) => {
    const authHeader = req.headers['authorization'];
    console.log(authHeader)
    if (authHeader) {
        const token = authHeader.split(' ')[1];

        jwt.verify(token, accessTokenSecret, (err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.sendStatus(403);
            }

            req.user = user;
            next();
        });
    } else {
        res.sendStatus(401);
    }
};
```

And finally, I access a route to test, req.headers['authorization'] does not have values.

```
app.get("/check",authenticateJWT,function(req, res){
    res.send("ok")
})
```

please help me, thanks

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

So when you are calling the API form the frontend or say you are checking the API with [postman](https://www.postman.com/) are you setting up the header while requesting `/check`? (I am not talking about your `/createJWT` which creates the token and sends it as a response)

In your frontend code/postman you need to explicitly add the header `authorization JWTtoken` while creating an HTTP request and after that your backend will receive it. Kindly check if this is not being done.

Comment: In case, I want to make login function in my apps. What will I should do? I just think that when token is signed, It is assiged directly to req.headers['authorization']. Does any ways to store it to request??

Comment: @PhanVănThành sorry for reaching out so late. Are you still stuck with it?